# If select options text color is red show alert on the screen when selected the option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a selectbox and inside options below,

```html
<select id="car_brands">
  <option style="color: red">BMW</option>
  <option style="color: red">Mercedes</option>
  <option>Toyota</option>
  <option>Nissan</option>
  <option style="color: red">Honda</option>
</select>
```

I want to get an alert message in jquery, "this car's model is BMW, etc.." **when I click red ones**. If I click other I don't want to see any alert message on the screen. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sidepoint: style should be end with semikolon `style="color: red;"`

Comment: This [answer (how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element) may helps you

Comment: @MaximilianFixl - `;` in CSS is a **separator**, not a terminator; [details](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#syntax-description). It's absolutely fine and normal not to have them in the above.

Comment: Dear @MaximilianFixl thanks I checked the link but I couldn't see a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var selectedCar = $('#car_brands').find(":selected");

if(selectedCar[0].style.color == "red"){
  console.log(`Selected car is ${selectedCar.text()}`)
}
```

most basic way I can think of. Can be made even simpler given time.

Answer (score 2):

Get the current selection and check if the color is red with `crt.style.color`

```js
function getSelected(optionSelected) {
  const crt = optionSelected.options[optionSelected.selectedIndex]
  if (crt.style.color === "red") {
    alert("This car's model is " + crt.text)
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="car_brands" onChange="getSelected(this);">
  <option style="color: red">BMW</option>
  <option style="color: red">Mercedes</option>
  <option>Toyota</option>
  <option>Nissan</option>
  <option style="color: red">Honda</option>
</select>
```